# List of products and category with mysql

Tags: database, category, products

I want to ask, how to get a list of all products SKU and there categories
For example:

| SKU | category | image | price | msrp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | cat1/cat2/cat2 | /123.jpg | 123 | 145 |

with Mysql query

**edit**: What I have tried so far:

```sql
SELECT e.entity_id, e.sku, a.value FROM catalog_product_super_link b
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity AS e ON e.entity_id = b.product_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product AS cp ON cp.product_id = b.product_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar AS a ON a.entity_id = cp.category_id
WHERE b.parent_id=368538
GROUP BY b.product_id
```

Comment: i tried this `SELECT 
 e.entity_id, 
    e.sku, 
    a.value
   
    

FROM
 catalog_product_super_link b
LEFT JOIN
 catalog_product_entity AS e 
ON
 e.entity_id = b.product_id
LEFT JOIN 
 catalog_category_product AS cp 
  ON 
 cp.product_id = b.product_id 
LEFT JOIN 
 catalog_category_entity_varchar AS a
  ON  
 a.entity_id = cp.category_id
    
    
WHERE
 b.parent_id=368538
group by
 b.product_id` but i get null in my category field

Answer (score 0):

Magento saves ***product & category associations*** in the ***catalog_category_product*** table.

and Sku is saved at product main table `catalog_product_entity`.Now using query you  can ***fulfill your requirement***

### Mysql query like

> ```
> SELECT cat.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT( cat.category_id ) , product.sku
> FROM catalog_category_product AS cat, catalog_product_entity AS product
> WHERE cat.product_id = product.entity_id
> GROUP BY cat.product_id
> ```

Comment: i try to get a list of product from catalog_product_super_link with SKU of children products, name of parent, categories of all children in one row and price,

Comment: SKU   title  category  available  link image price  msrp

Comment: i tried this `SELECT 
 e.entity_id, 
    e.sku, 
    a.value
   
    

FROM
 catalog_product_super_link b
LEFT JOIN
 catalog_product_entity AS e 
ON
 e.entity_id = b.product_id
LEFT JOIN 
 catalog_category_product AS cp 
  ON 
 cp.product_id = b.product_id 
LEFT JOIN 
 catalog_category_entity_varchar AS a
  ON  
 a.entity_id = cp.category_id
    
    
WHERE
 b.parent_id=368538
group by
 b.product_id` but i get null in my category field

Comment: ooo, you have chnage your requirement.then pleas the question...

Comment: i need the name of the categories instead there IDs

Comment: how to get product name also?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query will be like this:

```sql
SELECT product.entity_id as product_id, product.sk [Other attributes here]
FROM catalog_product_entity as product
INNER JOIN catalog_category_product as cat_prod ON product.entity_id = cat_prod.product_id
WHERE cat_prod.category_id IN [YOUR Category IDs];
```